# SPO Powershell Folder.Files ListItemAllFields Not Accessing Custom Property

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

On Sharepoint Online, using Powershell/CSOM, I am iterating through Doc Library folder set, retrieving the Folder.Files, iterating through the files, and trying to match a custom field value in the list item associated with that file.

Microsoft says File.ListItemAllFields should provide all of the fields and values I need, but it isn't retrieving the custom field value that I'm looking for.

Here is a simplified powershell snippet:

```
# Get Target List
$list = $lists.GetByTitle($Lib + " Library")
$ctx.Load($list)
$ctx.Load($list.RootFolder)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

# Get List Folders
$folders = $list.RootFolder.Folders 
$ctx.Load($folders)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$folders = $folders | sort Name

foreach ($folder in $folders)
{
    $files = $folder.Files
    $ctx.Load($files)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    foreach ($file in $files)
    {
        $ctx.Load($file)
        $ctx.Load($file.ListItemAllFields)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        if($file["IPGroup"] -eq $IPGroup)
        { 
            "File {0} has IPGroup {1}..." -f $file.Name, $file["IPGroup"] | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green; continue 
        }
    }
}
```

The custom field "IPGroup" is not being returned by the File.ListItemAllFields property.

What am I doing wrong (this time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that $item.get_item('fieldname') is all I needed!

This is how I modified the above code:

```
    $ctx.Load($file)
    $ctx.Load($file.ListItemAllFields)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    $item = $file.ListItemAllFields
    $ctx.Load($item)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    $name = $file.Name
    $group = $item.get_item('IPGroup')

    if($group -eq $IPGroup)
    { 
        "File {0} has IPGroup {1}..." -f $name, $group | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green; continue 
    }
```

Hope this saves someone a few hours of headscratching :)